# How to exclude filenames from Ag search (via fzf.vim)?

Tags: plugin-fzf, plugin-ag.vim

I'm using (the fantastic) Ag, Silver Searcher, through (the fantastic) fzf.vim plugin. When I search for text, though, I don't want to see matches on file names.

For example,

```
:Ag finder
```

shows every line in every file that has the word finder in it, when all I want is the files that actually have the word finder *in* them.

Comment: How about `--[no]filename`?

Answer (score 3):

To find files which contains some string, the `:grep` command is "for that".  And I know it's quite slow.

For that purpose, I have added the `:Find` command to my `.vimrc`:  (From this [post](https://medium.com/@crashybang/supercharge-vim-with-fzf-and-ripgrep-d4661fc853d2))

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Find call fzf#vim#grep('rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --no-ignore --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*" --color "always" '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1, <bang>0)
```

Note that with `--fixed-strings` we don't have to quote the string so we theoretically should just do `:Find a string with space`

By the way I am also using `set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep` so instead of the original slow `:grep` or `:Ag`, I can use `:grep finder` to find **files that contains the word "finder"**, powered by `rg`.

And use `:Ag` (or `:FZF`) to find **files that has "finder" in their names**.

Hope this helps.